# C++ Paint rectangle on form given array of pixel data

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm reading image data in as a multidimensional array of RGB data, and want to draw it on the form at a location in WM_PAINT

I know how to read a whole bitmap from file and paint it at a location:

```
    case WM_PAINT:
        PAINTSTRUCT     ps;
        HDC             hdc;
        BITMAP          bitmap;
        HDC             hdcMem;
        HGDIOBJ         oldBitmap;

        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        oldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);

        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBitmap);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
```

But not how to pain specific pixel data as a bitmap on the form. I've looked for literal days.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Create a bitmap from the pixel data. Look at functions like `CreateDibSection()`, `CreateDIBitmap()`, `SetDIBits()`, `SetDIBitsToDevice()`, etc. Then draw the bitmap onto your form as you normally would

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, use [CreateDibSection(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection).

Minimal example usage below:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"createdibsection_example";
    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        return 1;

    if (!CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName,
        L"createdibsection example",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, hInstance, NULL))
        return 2;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

    return 0;
}

HBITMAP CreateBitmapAndFillPtrToItsData(unsigned char** ptr_data, int wd, int hgt)
{
    HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);

    BITMAPINFO bmi;
    memset(&bmi, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = wd;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -hgt; // top-down
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    auto bmp = CreateDIBSection(hdcScreen, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**) ptr_data, NULL, NULL);

    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
    return bmp;
}

void CopyInPixelData(unsigned char* ptr_data, int wd, int hgt)
{
    // this is just an example for tutorial purposes ... generate a red circle
    // in a white field ... real code would load from a file, etc.

    int c_x = wd / 2;
    int c_y = hgt / 2;
    int radius = c_x;
    int i = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < hgt; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < wd; x++) {
            if ((x-c_x)*(x-c_x) + (y-c_y)*(y-c_y) <= radius*radius) {
                ptr_data[i++] = 0;
                ptr_data[i++] = 0;
                ptr_data[i++] = 255;
                ptr_data[i++] = 0;
            } else {
                ptr_data[i++] = 255;
                ptr_data[i++] = 255;
                ptr_data[i++] = 255;
                ptr_data[i++] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

HBITMAP CreateBitmapFromPixelDataExample(int wd, int hgt)
{
    // create a bitmap such that we get a pointer to where its data is stored
    unsigned char* ptr_data;
    auto bitmap = CreateBitmapAndFillPtrToItsData( &ptr_data, wd, hgt );

    // fill in some pixel data...
    CopyInPixelData( ptr_data, wd, hgt );

    return bitmap;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HBITMAP bitmap;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE: {
        bitmap = CreateBitmapFromPixelDataExample(85, 85);
    } break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT: {
        RECT r;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &r);

        auto hdc_bitmap = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
        auto hbm_old = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdc_bitmap, bitmap);

        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        auto hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // clear bkgd
        FillRect(hdc, &r, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
        // paint in the bitmap we generated from pixel data...
        BitBlt(hdc, 10, 10, 85, 85, hdc_bitmap, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        SelectObject(hdc_bitmap, hbm_old);
        DeleteDC(hdc_bitmap);

    } break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in the format that it takes, how would one set a specific x,y rgb point in ptr_data?

Comment: the pixel format depends on the values of biCompression and biBitCount passed in the BITMAPINMFOHEADER structure. I just updated the the code above to be more forgiving. When you pass BI_RGB as biCompression you are saying that tou are going to just list RGB values and then biBitCount says how many bits per pixel, which you normally want either 24 or 32 for i.e. three bytes per-pixel with a byte for alpha or not. Data is layed out row-by-row and must be DWORD aligned. If you set 32 bits per pixel, as I have it now, you do not have to worry about padding rows/alignment.